# Reactjs HistoryLocation get 404 on refresh

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, browserify, react-router

I'm building an app in Laravel and just started doing front end UI with **reactjs**.

After I enabled `HistoryLoaction` in **react-router**, whenever I refresh a page, it doesnt stay the same displaying the components rendered from react, instead, it hits my api endpoints and returns data in json back in the browser.

I figured its because my backend api routes and react routes are the same. But if I make the backend routes different from the **react** routes, it'll just get "http not found" on refresh instead.

Is there a way to prevent this in react, react-router or laravel? maybe a way to make the page rerender the components on page refresh?

Update:

In **react-router** doc, it says you must configure your server to use `HistoryLocation`. But I dont quite understand how to configure. does it mean I need to direct all requests to one view? Then how do I make GET and POST request in react components?

Thanks.

Comment: You've answered this question yourself really.

Comment: then how do i make GET and POST request with ajax in react components when all the routes are directed to one view?

Comment: You make your api routes different.

Comment: oops that was a no brainer...