# Is it possible to configure IIS (specifically, in Azure) to work with HistoryLocation?

Tags: azure, iis, reactjs, react-router

I have React app which ends up being built with webpack. We host an API which this app talks to on Azure and would like to host the UI built on top of it out there as well.

When hitting the URL the first time, and navigating around, all of the history location stuff works. However, when we refresh the page, we receive a 404 error (which is to be expected if IIS is serving this).

Is it possible to configure Azure to handle this sort of thing? Should we just give up on this type of application and host a webpack vm?

Similar questions:

[Reactjs HistoryLocation get 404 on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940581/reactjs-historylocation-get-404-on-refresh)

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

Comment: Really _a_ solution is to redirect all folder routes to index.html - but not sure if you can do that with rewrite rules on Azure

Comment: what is your server technology? NodeJS ? And exactly cannot be handled correctly ? Specific request to given path or what? Give more details for the #Azure and #IIS folks who are not necessarily mastering other technologies too.

Comment: Server technology is IIS in this case. If there is a react router path that is /some/route, refreshing this page on IIS will result in a 404.

Comment: so you just put one simple HTML page (say index.html) and all you do is on the client side with JS, there is no server side programming of any sort?

Comment: Correct. It may just be that the answer is to _not_ use this sort of Azure Web App deployment. Just seemed more convenient. As I understand it, HistoryLocation requires that all route requests be served as "index.html"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If do understand your question and situation correctly, the solution would be to redirect all requests to your only one HTML page (assuming index.html). 
This can be achieved with the [URL rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) of IIS.

By default any Azure Web App will have a file in its web root folder named `web.config`. This is standard XML file. Open it with favorite editor and locate `<system.webserver>` section. Then place the following additional sections inside. Note, the `<rewrite>` element should be direct descendant of the `<system.webserver>` one:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to index.html">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Again, based on the assumption that you serve everything from `index.html`, you can change this file in the rewrite rule to represent the file you are serving content from.

Comment: This ended up being the answer, although to host _just_ the items out on Azure required a slightly different web.config.